# What is the meaning of "pass" in "in passing"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

"in passing" means briefly, by the way, incidentally, ...

Is "pass" in it a verb? A intransitive verb?

What is its meaning? I can't find one from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passes

Answer (score 2):

It's a participle, with the verb used in a figurative extension of sense 3.a:

> to move in a path so as to approach and continue beyond something :
> move past

''By the way'' is almost the same metaphor.

Comment: Makes me wonder whether ***while we're on the subject*** could be seen as metaphoric *temporal* as opposed to *spatial* proximity in the context of the "course" of the conversation. Come to that, given expressions like *over the course of the day*, I'm not sure whether *the course of the conversation* should be seen as a temporal or spatial metaphoric usage.

Comment: **while we are on** is a space-time continuum.